# Why did Chewie not get a Medal or anything?

Tags: character, star-wars, a-new-hope

In **Star Wars**, why did Chewbacca not get a medal when the others did, during the celebration ceremony for the destruction of the original/prototype Death Star?

Comment: [Tackled](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6537/why-didnt-chewbacca-get-a-medal-after-the-battle-of-yavin) on SF&F, though TBH I don't see a definitive answer there to this exact question.

Comment: I don't think there's a good answer. I've heard this asked for many years, and have never seen an answer. At least not Canon. The novelization awards him if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe only Lucas really knows, but I've always assumed it's because both Luke and Han are their ships' captains, so as Chewie was only co pilot he does not get the same recognition. Those were the two ships directly responsible for the Death Star's downfall, Luke the shooter, Han the protector.

Chewbacca did not make the decision to risk going in to protect Luke to make the shot.